# Progress bar is not working in BackgroundWorker VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a progress bar to show while a method is being executed. I've called BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() from a button. Then in the DoWork I call the method to run "runCopyFiles". I update the progress in ProgressChanged, and exit with RunWorkerCompleted. I'm not sure what I have wrong. I've searched the net for tutorials and examples on how to do this and have created the code from them. But the progress bar doesn't show.

Code For executing from button

```
Private Sub btnExecuteFileCopy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecuteFileCopy.Click
    Me.Refresh()
    If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = True Then
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub
```

Code for BackGroundWorker

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    Const Max As Integer = 1000

    For i = 1 To Max
        '' do something
        '' (I put a sleep to simulate time consumed)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

        '' report progress at regular intervals
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(100 * i / Max), "Running..." & i.ToString)

        '' check at regular intervals for CancellationPending
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(100 * i / Max), "Cancelling...")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    runCopyFiles()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    lblStatus.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " %"
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        MsgBox(" Operation Cancelled ")
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        lblStatus.Text = ""
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(e.Error.Message)
    Else
        MsgBox(" Process Complete ")
    End If
End Sub
```

Code RunCopy

```
Private Sub runCopyFiles()

    Application.UseWaitCursor = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    Me.Refresh()

    Dim sFileToFind As String
    Dim location As String
    Dim File As String
    'Dim createReportFldr As String
    'Dim createXMLFldr As String
    'Dim createImgFldr As String

    'Directory Files are located in
    location = txtFolderPath.Text
    'Directory files are to copied into
    MoveLocation = CopyToPath

    createImgFldr = MoveLocation & "\Figures"
    createReportFldr = MoveLocation & "\Reports"
    createXMLFldr = MoveLocation & "\XML files"

    'Create Figures Folder
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(createImgFldr) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createImgFldr)
        ' MsgBox("folder created" & createFolder)
    End If
    'Create Reports folder
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(createReportFldr) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createReportFldr)
        'MsgBox("folder created" & createReportFldr)
    End If
    'Create XML folder
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(createXMLFldr) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(createXMLFldr)
        ' MsgBox("folder created" & createFolder)
    End If


    orphanedFiles = MoveLocation & "\Reports\OrphanedFilesItems.txt"
    ' Create or overwrite the file.
    System.IO.File.Create(orphanedFiles).Dispose()

    ListofFiles = MoveLocation & "\Reports\ListOfFiles.txt"
    ' Create or overwrite the file.  
    System.IO.File.Create(ListofFiles).Dispose()

    MissingFiles = MoveLocation & "\Reports\MissingGraphicList.txt"
    ' Create or overwrite the file.  
    System.IO.File.Create(MissingFiles).Dispose()

    Dim FILE_NAME As String

    FILE_NAME = txtFileName.Text

    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
    Dim sFile As String
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        File = objReader.ReadLine()
        sFileToFind = location & "\" & File & "*.*"
        sFile = File

        Dim paths() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(location, sFile, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        If paths.Count = 0 Then
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(orphanedFiles, sFile & vbNewLine)
            ' Debug.Print(File)
            'If System.IO.File.Exists(orphanedFiles) = True Then
            '    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(orphanedFiles, IO.FileMode.Append)
            '    objWriter.WriteLine(File)
            '    objWriter.Close()
            'Else
            'MsgBox("Creating Orphaned File Now. ")
            'End If
        Else
            For Each pathAndFileName As String In paths
                Dim moveToFolder As String

                If System.IO.File.Exists(pathAndFileName) = True Then
                    Dim sRegLast As String = pathAndFileName.Substring(pathAndFileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
                    Dim toFileLoc As String

                    'MsgBox("sRegLast " & sRegLast)
                    ' fileLoc = MoveLocation & sRegLast
                    moveToFolder = MoveLocation & "\XML files\" & sRegLast
                    toFileLoc = createXMLFldr & "\" & sRegLast
                    'MsgBox("FileLoc " & fileLoc)

                    'if toFileLoc = XML file exists move it into the XML files folder
                    If System.IO.File.Exists(toFileLoc) = False Then
                        System.IO.File.Copy(pathAndFileName, moveToFolder)
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(ListofFiles, sRegLast & vbNewLine)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Loop
    'MsgBox("Files have been moved")

    Call CreateGraphicsFunction(Nothing, System.EventArgs.Empty)
    Call getImages()
    MsgBox("Process Complete", MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton1)
    Application.UseWaitCursor = False
    Application.DoEvents()
    ' Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to call `runCopyFiles()` exactly 101 times? What is `runCopyFiles()` doing here? Are you maybe performing the same operation 101 times?

Comment: I guess once `runCopyFiles` is done, you cancel the BackgroundWorker, so your progress is only reported once (zero). But we can't see `runCopyFiles` so who knows

Comment: Oh no didn't want to runCopy a 100 times at all.

Comment: @djv I've updated my question with the runCopy code

Comment: Make sure you are not doing any UI work from other threads than main thread, which is a dispatcher thread.

Comment: @MaxineHammett I see that, and I also see you still aren't using `Using`, which we've gone over in your previous questions :P

Comment: @djv I admit I'm still not sure how to use using

Comment: Start with removing all `Application.DoEvents()` and `Me.Refresh()`. You can't have a reference to UI objects here. Your proc will probably jump out of context.

Comment: Have you checked if the WorkerReportsProgress properties is set to True (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @emoreau99  That's true. It's nowhere to be seen here. If it's not set, no progress. Many more issues need to be fixed before getting there, anyway.

Comment: There's no good reason in VB.Net to **ever** use the `Call` keyword. It's a holdover from the vb6 era for backwards compatibility, but has no meaning anymore.

Comment: In addition to the last @Jimi comment, you should not access other UI elements such as `FILE_NAME = txtFileName.Text` and `location = txtFolderPath.Text`. These paths should be moved from controls to variables before this runs.

Comment: OK I removed the do events and the refresh. Still not working. Will now make the changes djv suggests. Thank you for giving me input on how to make my code better

Comment: Wouldn't an event have to be fired from the background worker to tell the UI that the progress has changed?

Comment: I added BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True and that made the progress bar work. But how do I get it to work within DoWork. Right now I have the method to run outside of the For code because I don't want the code to run a hundred times.

Comment: As other have said, your code is a bit strange. One thing I just saw is that you have a loop that calls ReportProgress but your RunCopyFiles is outside that loop. If all you want is to show some progress while copying files, have a look at https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/performance/displaying-the-windows-copy-dialog-box-when-copying-files-through-.net.html

Comment: Yes I realize i have the code outside the loop. I had it in the loop before and that made the method run 100 times. How would I make sure the backgroundWorker runs in sync with the method calling it?

Comment: wouldn't your ReportProgress better be called in your "For Each pathAndFileName As String In paths" loop and the DoWork method simply calls the RunCopyFiles method?

Answer (score 0):

If you loop while there are more lines in your file, there's no way to know how many total lines there are, and that is a crucial component in the percent calculation for the progress bar:

> percent = 100 * currentFile / totalFiles

So instead, we can read all lines up front and iterate over them. This should be your `runCopyFiles`

```
Dim fileNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
For i = 0 To fileNames.Count() - 1
    Dim fileName = fileNames(i)
    sFileToFind = location & "\" & fileName & "*.*"

    Dim paths = IO.Directory.GetFiles(location, fileName, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    If Not paths.Any() Then
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(orphanedFiles, fileName & vbNewLine)
    Else
        For Each pathAndFileName As String In paths
            If System.IO.File.Exists(pathAndFileName) = True Then
                Dim sRegLast = pathAndFileName.Substring(pathAndFileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
                Dim toFileLoc = System.IO.Path.Combine(createXMLFldr, sRegLast)
                Dim moveToFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(moveLocation, "XML files", sRegLast)

                'if toFileLoc = XML file exists move it into the XML files folder
                If System.IO.File.Exists(toFileLoc) = False Then
                    System.IO.File.Copy(pathAndFileName, moveToFolder)
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(ListofFiles, sRegLast & vbNewLine)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 * i / fileNames.Count())
Next
```

That is where the progress should be reported.

And all you should have in your DoWork is this

```vb
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    runCopyFiles()
End Sub
```

You never need `Application.DoEvents`, and if you find that you do need it, then **you are doing something wrong**. DoWork calls code on a background thread which

1. Shouldn't access the UI without invoking calls on the UI thread
2. In turn doesn't block the UI from updating...

... which is really why you use it - so you can run processing code behind the UI without slowing it down.

In total, here are all the things you should remember to do

- Don't access UI from background thread
- Use `Using` to automatically dispose IDisposable objects
- Use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to combine paths instead of using string concatenation
- Don't call `runCopyFiles` 101 times
- `BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress` is meant to be called when you are doing work
- `If booleanValue = True Then` is redundant, just do `If booleanValue Then`

Comment: Thank you @djv. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me.